# Postgresql change the year range and input order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form

I have a `date_of_birth` field with type `date` and I need to correct the following two issues:

1. The year range is limiting to 2010..2020
2. The order of the fields is YYYY - MM - DD and I would like it to be MM - DD - YYYY

Comment: For the first question.You can try `date_select` like this `date_select("model", "date_of_birth", start_year: 2010, end_year: 2020, include_blank: true)`

Comment: @Paven Thanks your tip lead me to my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the desired output as follows (strictly with simple_form):

```
<%= f.input(:date_of_birth, start_year: 1900, end_year: Time.now.year - 1, order: [:month, :day, :year]) %>
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)